# Salvaging a DataEase application

Tags: rad

I've been asked to become the maintainer of a [DataEase](http://www.dataease.com) application after my customer had a few "problems" with the original developer.. I know nothing about DataEase (never heard of it before today, in fact), and my customer can't provide me with the original sources... Are they somehow "de-compilable" from the application itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sources are tied to the database. You need DataEase Version related to the application and high level password.

Answer (score 2):

DataEase applications are not compiled. But you need a copy of DataEase, either DOS or Windows depending on what you've been given.

Comment: So DataEase would allow me to edit the application itself? Great, thanks!